# Map associated to linear system onto curve is morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, characteristic-p, minimal-model-program, positive-characteristic

In Mumford's first paper on Surfaces in char $p$ [1], part 2 Step (II), he wants to show that, given an indecomposable curve of canonical type $D$ on a smooth projective surface $F$ with $p_g(F)=0, K_F^2=0, K_F$ nef, $|nD|$ is composite with a pencil of curves of canonical type for some $n$.

He goes on to show the existance of a disjoint indecomposable curve of canonical type $D'$, and that $|2K+2D+2D'|$ is composite with a pencil of curves of canonical type.

My question arises here: In the next sentence he says that since $D.(2K+2D+2D')=0$, $D$ must be a fiber of said pencil. This seems to make sense only if the map given by $|2K+2D+2D'|$ is in fact a morphism / defined everywhere, which does not seem obvious.

In [2, p. 96], Badescu follows the same argument, but adds some detail.
He shows that $\phi_{|2K+2D+2D'|}(F)=B$ is of dimension $1$. He then concludes that

> Thus $|2K+2D+2D'|$ is indeed composed with a pencil, and $\phi_{|2K+2D+2D'|}$ is a
>   morphism.

Let $\Delta \in |2K+2D+2D'|$. As far as I know, since in this case $\kappa(\Delta) = \nu(\Delta)=1$ (and $R(L)$ is finitely generated; $\nu = $ numerical Kodaira dimension), wherefore $\Delta$ is semi-ample. So some multiple of $\Delta$ would give a morphism, and it seems the rest of the argument in the paper would still work.

However, afaik the reference I could find for this fact is much more recent than Mumford's paper (which is from 1977). So I assume there must be a better, more elementary way to see that $\phi_{|\Delta|}$ is a morphism?

**EDIT**
The references I mentioned are [3] and [4].

*[1] Mumford, D. - Enriques' classification of surfaces in char $p$: I, from "Global Analysis, Papers in Honor of K. Kodaira"*

*[2] Badescu, L. - Algebraic Surfaces*

*[3] Mourougane; Russo - Some Remarks on Nef and Good Divisors on an Algebraic Variety ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0764444297888969))*

*[4] Kawamata - Pluricanonical Systems on Minimal Algebraic Varieties ([link](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01388524.pdf))*

Comment: What precisely is your question?  Are you asking for an earlier reference?

Comment: @JasonStarr Sorry if I was not clear. Yes, either an earlier reference, or a more elementary way to see why $\phi$ is a morphism.